# Error in Reinxdeing in Magento

Tags: php, magento

1.I m adding a configurable product in magento ,with some price and after adding sale tag over it for a particular duration it still shows up after the end of the date. Price is showing different on the page where all products are listed and different when I open it.

2.Sale product price do not update to back to normal after sale ends.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From call backtrace you can assume that *OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts* is causing the issue. Module probably rewrote product price indexer model.

I have never seen this module before, so I can't provide anything further info. You should probably try disabling it and re-running the indexing.

As for the `count` column that's causing the issue, it was probably created by same module since it shouldn't exist out of the box.

Best of luck.